# Set coordinates as default value

Tags: postgis, latitude-longitude, default

In PostGIS, how to set default value with st_x or st_y ? I want to populate automatically two fields with lon and lat when I create a point.

Comment: Maybe with triggers like in here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328090/automatically-add-points-geometry-while-gps-logging. But if you define a view then there is no need to populate anything.

Comment: Generated columns might be a good choice here.

Answer (score 3):

Make your database PostGIS ready (e.g. CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS;)
Create a table with geometry/geography column and add a default value to the column?

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
id int primary key,
pos geometry(POINT, 3857, 2) DEFAULT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 0),3857));
```

You can insert record without *pos* column to get a point in the origin

```
INSERT INTO test1 (id) VALUES (1);
SELECT id, ST_AsText(pos);

 id | st_astext  
----+------------
  1 | POINT(0 0)
(1 row)
```